# How to get count of several/all same strings in document of MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm new to MongoDb and have 2 questions about $group and $sum in $aggregate.

F.e. i have collection "users" with documents (_id i've omitted for simplicity):

```
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:100,
    description:null
},
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:102,
    description:null
},
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:100,
    description:"text"
},
{
    user_id:2,
    group_id:102,
    description:"another text"
},
{
    user_id:3,
    group_id:101,
    description:"another text"
}
```

**The 1st question is:** how to get result like this?

How to $group by all strings and count it?

Not sure about syntax, but i think logic is clear.

```
{
user_id: [
1: 
      count:3,
2:
      count:1,
3:
      count:1],
group_id: [
100:
      count:2,
101:
      count:1,
102:
      count:2],
description: [
null:
      count: 2,
"text":
      count: 1,
"another text":
      count:2]
}
```

**And the 2nd question**:

How to group by "user_id" and count other fields?

With "user_id":1 i have group_id(100) - 2, group_id(102) - 1, etc.

```
{
user_id: 1,
group_id: [
100:
      count: 2,
102:
      count: 1],
description: [
null:
      count: 2,
"text":
      count: 1]
},

{
user_id: 2,
group_id: [
102:
      count: 1],
description: [
"another text":
      count: 1]
},

{
user_id: 3,
group_id: [
101:
      count: 1],
description: [
"another text":
      count: 1]
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Please can you be more explicit and explain your question in a better way? Is not clear how you want to group values. Also, please, provide a valid JSON format for your desired output.

Comment: What do you want to count?

Comment: @J.F. i've updated post, ty.

Comment: @GalAbra in 1st question i want to count every string in all documents. f.e. "user_id":1 count is 3, "description": "another text" - count is 2.
in 2nd question i want to group by "user_id" and count other fields.